# Coloring of expander

Tags: c#, templates, silverlight, listbox, expander

I have an Expander that has: **Expander header and listbox inside.**
I want to create the following situation.

a. when **hover on expander head** - color its head background in blue.
b. when **hover** on expanders' **listbox item** color it in gray.
c. when expanders' listbox **item is selected** i want 2 things to happen:

1. listbox item background  is colored with gray
2. expanders' header background is colored with blue.

my question is how to do it with silverlight.

thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Expander control has a Background Property which is bounded to its embeded Border control via TemplateBinding here:

```
<Border x:Name="Background" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                             ...
```

Try to change the corresponding Background property of the expander control via adding the following line to the Expander Style.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#000000"></Setter>
```

Like this you can change the **Background** property of the `listbox control` also.